# Rails 3: Why "link_to" gives wrong output?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, link-to

In my view file I type the following:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><%= link_to(tag(:div, {:class => "my_class"}), "my_address") %></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

The result is: (observed in Firebug)

```
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <a href="my_address"></a>
        <div class="my_class"></div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Why the `div` is not inside `a` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `content_tag`, not `tag`.

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><%= link_to(content_tag(:div, { :class => "my_class" }), "my_address") %></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Honestly, in this case I prefer to use a block.

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
    <%= link_to "my_address" do %>
      <div class="my_class"></div>
    <% end %>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Rails doesn't perform any kind of HTML validation thus I didn't take into consideration the implication about valid/invalid HTML resulting from your code.

Answer (score 2):

According to [Is putting a div inside a anchor ever correct?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1827965/is-putting-a-div-inside-a-anchor-ever-correct), you can only place inline elements inside of an anchor. `<div>` is a block element, so your code will not work. You'll need to use something like `<span>` to wrap whatever data you intend to put in the anchor.

The first post does go on to say that HTML5 allows `<a>` to contain blocks though, so if you are defining HTML5 as your doctype then we need to dig deeper.

Answer (score 0):

You can't have `div` inside a `<a>` tag. Use `<span>` or `<p>` instead

Comment: `<p>` is a block level element as well, which won't work for the same reasons `<div>` won't.

Comment: `<%= link_to(content_tag(:div, "New Page"), new_page_path) %>`  I tried this and `div` was in side `<a>`.    Using rails 3.0.5

Answer (score 0):

You cannot put block elements inside inline elements. If you are trying to link the div, you should use this:

```
 tag(:div, {:class => "my_class", :onclick => "my_address"})
```

Otherwise, use `span` instead of `div`